# How to create new column with multiple conditions in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a df as below format.

```
    year    type1   type2   price
    2015    apple   natural 40
    2015    apple   organic 35
    2016    apple   natural 44
    2016    apple   organic 40
    2015    banana  natural 20
    2015    banana  organic 15
    2016    banana  natural 20
    2016    banana  organic 18
```

I need to create a new column `price_new` when the `year`, `type1` and `type2` conditions are met. In other words for the same `year` and `type1` if the `type2` is `natural` then fill the new column with new value or else print the old value.

I tried the below:

```
df["price_new"] = np.where(((df["year"] == 2015) & (
                    df["type1"] == "apple") & (df["type2"].isin(['natural']))),
                                                    25, df["price"])
df["price_new"] = np.where(((df["year"] == 2016) & (
                    df["type1"] == "apple") & (df["type2"].isin(['natural']))),
                                                    26, df["price"])

df["price_new"] = np.where(((df["year"] == 2015) & (
                    df["type1"] == "apple") & (~df["type2"].isin(['natural']))),
                                                    20, df["price"])

df["price_new"] = np.where(((df["year"] == 2016) & (
                    df["type1"] == "apple") & (~df["type2"].isin(['natural']))),
                                                    22, df["price"])
```

The output should be like below:

```
year    type1   type2   price   price_new
2015    apple   natural 40     25
2015    apple   organic 35     20
2016    apple   natural 44     26
2016    apple   organic 40     22
2015    banana  natural 20
2015    banana  organic 15
2016    banana  natural 20
2016    banana  organic 18
```

However, the values from only the last condition are printed:

```
 year   type1   type2   price   price_new
    2015    apple   natural 40     40
    2015    apple   organic 35     35
    2016    apple   natural 44     44
    2016    apple   organic 40     22
    2015    banana  natural 20
    2015    banana  organic 15
    2016    banana  natural 20
    2016    banana  organic 18
```

1. How could the `price_new` column get the new values for all conditions
2. In real data i have more than 10 types in `type1` column. Is there an efficient way to write this instead of writing it for each unique value in `type1` column?

Comment: I edited my answer to include question #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answering first question:**

- First copy all prices into `price_new`
- Then use `df["price_new"]` as the default value in `np.where` calls

```py
df["price_new"] = df["price"]
df["price_new"] = np.where(condition, value, df["price_new"])
```

**Answering second question:**

You can reduce code by putting all conditions and corresponding values into a suitable data structure (here list of named tuples), and then use it to generate boolean masks (`condlist`) used by [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) that will compute your result.

Note that I use dicts and [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html) when computing masks so masks that appear more than once are only computed once.

```py
from collections import namedtuple

Condition = namedtuple("Condition", ["year", "type1", "type2"])
Mapping = namedtuple("Mapping", ["condition", "value"])

mappings = [
    Mapping(Condition(year=2015, type1="apple", type2="natural"), value=25),
    Mapping(Condition(year=2016, type1="apple", type2="natural"), value=26),
    Mapping(Condition(year=2015, type1="apple", type2="organic"), value=20),
    Mapping(Condition(year=2016, type1="apple", type2="organic"), value=22),
]

conditions, values = zip(*mappings)

years, types1, types2 = {}, {}, {}
condlist = [
    (
        years.setdefault(year, df["year"] == year)
        & types1.setdefault(type1, df["type1"] == type1)
        & types2.setdefault(type2, df["type2"] == type2)
    )
    for year, type1, type2 in conditions
]

df["price_new"] = np.select(condlist, values, default=df["price"])
```

Check if it works as expected:

```py
expected = [25, 20, 26, 22, 20, 15, 20, 18]
print(f"{np.all(df['price_new'] == expected) = }")  # True
```

**Old answer**:

You can put all your conditions and matching values into a suitable data structure, and then process with computation.

Here I choose a list of tuples (named tuples for clarity) where first element of the tuple is the condition and second element is the corresponding value.

```py
from collections import namedtuple

Mapping = namedtuple("Mapping", ["where", "value"])

mappings = [
    Mapping(
        where=(
            (df["year"] == 2015)
            & (df["type1"] == "apple")
            & (df["type2"].isin(["natural"]))
        ),
        value=25,
    ),
    Mapping(
        where=(
            (df["year"] == 2016)
            & (df["type1"] == "apple")
            & (df["type2"].isin(["natural"]))
        ),
        value=26,
    ),
    Mapping(
        where=(
            (df["year"] == 2015)
            & (df["type1"] == "apple")
            & (~df["type2"].isin(["natural"]))
        ),
        value=20,
    ),
    Mapping(
        where=(
            (df["year"] == 2016)
            & (df["type1"] == "apple")
            & (~df["type2"].isin(["natural"]))
        ),
        value=22,
    ),
]
```

From there you can either:

- Rewrite the previous code as a for loop:

```py
df["price_new_1"] = df["price"]
for where, value in mappings:
    df["price_new_1"] = np.where(where, value, df["price_new_1"])
```

- Use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to compute all at once:

```py
condlist, choicelist = zip(*mappings)
df["price_new_2"] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default=df["price"])
```

Check if it works as expected:

```py
expected = [25, 20, 26, 22, 20, 15, 20, 18]
print(f"{np.all(df['price_new_1'] == expected) = }")  # True
print(f"{np.all(df['price_new_2'] == expected) = }")  # True
```

Comment: so mappings has to be created for each `year` and `type1` combination, which means that the same lines of code as if one would do something like  in my OP. Any  other ways to minimize the lines of code?

Comment: Ah yes I read the second part wrong. Since the `where` condition is always of the same structure, you can again minimize its writing by putting all the information in a list of tuples, and construct all with a for loop. On the other hand, it will prevent you to store e.g. `df["type2"].isin(["natural"])` (which is computed many times for no reason) in a variable.

Comment: I added a way to reduce code. But you still have to define all your cases, it can't be otherwise, except if you don't care about `type1` variable for example, then just drop the condition on it.